# How can I log back in to a Pokemon go account

Tags: pokemon-go

I was on like level 6 when the app crashed and made me log back in. I put all the same info but it took me back to level 1 and everything was lost. When I sign on and off it will only revert back to the new one. It made me make a new username and everything. Any ideas on how I can get my other progress back?

Comment: Yes the same exact account as I have no other one. Yea I contacted them but still no reply. I was getting impatient. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you used the same account you used last time? If you are very positive about this, then I would recommend contacting the Pokemon-Go support at https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com.